# How to do PostgreSQL replication on CentOS 7?

Tags: postgresql, replication, centos-7

Followed this guide to do the PostgreSQL replication:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-on-postgresql-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

I didn't do this:

```
psql -c "select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');"
rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/ slave_IP_address:/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/
psql -c "select pg_stop_backup();"
```

After I configed both master and slave nodes, test to create a table on master, didn't find new data been synced to slave.

From this guide I saw need to add a `archive_command` config in the `recovery.conf` file:

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=postgresql&f=3

```
archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/archive/%f'
```

But PostgreSQL 9.6 maybe not support that feature. So how can it been synced automatically?

---

## Addition

It's helpful:

https://dalibo.github.io/PAF/Quick_Start-CentOS-7.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `archive_command` setting doesn't fit the `recovery.conf` but the `postgresql.conf` file.

The documentation you're following is deprecated.

Please switch to the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html).

Here are the steps you need to perform:

- Primary node settings (`postgresql.conf`, `pg_hba.conf`)
- Primary node backup (`pg_basebackup`, `pgbarman`, `pgbackrest`... Whatever)
- Restoring on secondary node (manually, `pgbarman`, `pgbackrest`... Whatever)
- Secondary node settings (`recovery.conf`, `postgresql.conf`, eventually `pg_hba.conf`)

The part you didn't do is simply the initial backup/restore. You can't do replication without it.

Comment: Thank you. How to send the database data to slave on PostgreSQL 9.6? Maybe use archive path, but which is the archive path of 9.6? The sample is `rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/ slave_IP_address:/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/`, but there is no path like `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/main` with 9.6 version.

Comment: Maybe run this: `pg_basebackup -h master-ip -D ~postgres/9.6/data/ -X stream -P`, but run it on slave, then got this error: `pg_basebackup: directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data" exists but is not empty`.

Comment: I run `rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* ~postgres/9.6/data/ slave_ip:~postgres/9.6/data/` on master, then change to right info(IP) under `data` folder on slave, it works!

Comment: If you didn't use `psql -c "select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');"` before your rsync and `psql -c "select pg_stop_backup();"` after, you're just lucky it works...

Comment: I used that two psql commands.

Comment: Good for you. :-)